# CocoaPodHelper.cs `Process ` :type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to system.idisposable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

When I try to run my game in Unity3d it gives me this error in CocoaPodHelper.cs file in the compiler

Process ` :type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to system.idisposable

and anything after "`using (var process = new Process())`" is full of errors.

here is the code of the cocapodhelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

    namespace GoogleMobileAds
    {
        public class CocoaPodHelper
        {
            public static string Update(string projDir)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(projDir))
                {
                    throw new Exception("project not found: " + projDir);
                }

                string podPath = ExecuteCommand("which", "pod", null);
                if (podPath.Equals(""))
                {
                    throw new Exception("pod executable not found");
                }
                return ExecuteCommand(podPath.Trim(), "update", projDir);
            }

            private static string ExecuteCommand(string command, string argument, string workingDir)
            {

                using (var process = new Process())
                {
                    if (!process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.ContainsKey("LANG"))
                    {
                        process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("LANG", "en_US.UTF-8");
                    }

                    string path = process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"];
                    if(!path.Contains("/usr/local/bin"))
                    {
                        path = path + ":/usr/local/bin";
                        process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Remove("PATH");
                        process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("PATH", path);
                    }

                    if (workingDir != null)
                    {
                        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
                    }
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = command;
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Executing " + command + " argument: " +
                        process.StartInfo.Arguments);
                    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                    try
                    {
                        process.Start();
                        process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                        var stdOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                        var stdError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("command stdout: " + stdOutput);

                        if (stdError != null && stdError.Length > 0)
                        {
                            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("command stderr: " + stdError);
                        }

                        if (!process.WaitForExit(10 * 1000))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("command did not exit in a timely fashion");
                        }

                        return stdOutput;

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Encountered unexpected error while running pod", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Process` class does not implement `IDisposable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

A using statement allows the object in the statement to be "disposed of" after the end of the using statement - the statement will call a method to get rid of the object.  However, `System.Diagnostics.Process` does not "have" a method in it that allows it to be disposed of; it doesn't implement the `IDisposable` interface.  So, instead of having:
`using (var process = new Process()) { //Do stuff here }` just do:
`var process = new Process(); //Do stuff here` and the variable will go out of scope at the end of the method.